# Different results between PHP md5() and Ruby Digest::MD5.hexdigest

Tags: php, ruby, md5

I wanted to pass a MD5 hash generated by Ruby program to a PHP program, and found something strange.

## Ruby code(result: ad0efdf609e99ec50d9333dc0bd1c11a)

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest 'test str1&test str2&test str3&test str4'
```

## PHP code(result: 804160119894a4cc8c376fffbcc21e1c)

[PHP online MD5 generator](http://www.md5.cz/)

You can see the results are different... but if I remove the "&" in my string:

## Ruby code(result: 45fa91e4c89aa6f3bb501531a5de6bf4)

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest 'test str1test str2test str3test str4'
```

## PHP code(result: 45fa91e4c89aa6f3bb501531a5de6bf4)

[PHP online MD5 generator](http://www.md5.cz/)

They are the same. Why did this happen? The MD5 algorithm should be same in any language, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think these &$#% write different in strings per language. Sometimes it is written by 4 digit code. Have you try escape thise strings?

Comment: What is your default encoding? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753321/what-is-the-default-encoding-for-the-function-md5-in-php

Comment: I really hope you're not using these for passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results of that website are wrong.

Here comes an example (using PHP on the command line):

```
php -r 'echo md5("test str1&test str2&test str3&test str4");'
```

Output:

```
ad0efdf609e99ec50d9333dc0bd1c11a
```

Comment: Correct, the MD5 generator is actually running the hash of `test str1` in the first example.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was totally confused with the results. You saved me.

Comment: You are welcome. You could write an email to the owner of the site and inform him. I'm sure he will appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

`804160119894a4cc8c376fffbcc21e1c` is the MD5 hash for `test str1`, not `test str1&test str2&test str3&test str4`.

That on-line generator is obviously corrupting POST data <del>when reading it</del>. According to Firebug, data is already sent corrupted to the server, so the issue is on its client-side form handling. It's easy to find what's wrong:

```
function sendHttpRequest(w){
    var url = "http://www.md5.cz/getmd5.php";
    var idWhat = document.getElementById('what');
    var params = "what=" + idWhat.value;
                           ^^^^ Pardon???
```

The correct hash is `ad0efdf609e99ec50d9333dc0bd1c11a`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer and above are both excellent, I want to accept you two but I can't. So I only can vote you up :)